Is there a way to solve the ENOSPC error while creating react app?
Everything used to be working fine for me. I turned my laptop off. On the next day, when I tried to create a new react project, I started getting the errors below. Even though the npm install is not working with other projects. Those who prefer disk storage issue a solution let me clarify that I have 500gb free on my disk.
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/media/haseeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact/node_modules/es-abstract/CHANGELOG.md'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/media/haseeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact/node_modules/es-abstract/README.md'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/media/haseeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact/node_modules/es-abstract/operations/build-unicode.mjs'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/media/haseeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/package.json'
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR ENOSPC: no space left on device, open '/media/haseeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-x64/README.md'
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /media/haseeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact/node_modules/.bin
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/media/haseeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact/node_modules/.bin'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/haseeb/.npm/_logs/2024-04-10T18_19_03_063Z-debug-0.log
               
 [..eeb/New Volume/6th-Semester/web-Course/Mid-II_Prep/myToDoReact]
 ✘  haseeb  

If anyone has solved this issue, please let me know.

The error means that some file system involved in the installation is out of space. You can solve the problem by freeing up space or configuring the installation to use another file system.

Make sure that /media/haseeb/New_Volume really has enough space. df /media/haseeb/New_Volume will tell you if that's Linux or MacOS.

If you shut down your laptop and restarted, perhaps you forgot to re-mount the new file system.
